# How normalize non-uniform Python dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

dataframe-1 I am showing below was one row in my primary dataframe.

I used [][] notation to retrieve that only row I wanted as a dictionary from which I created this dataframe-1 below.

My question is how can I make all the 'keys' as columns and 'values' as row value and store it in dataframe-2?

I tried iterrows, itertuples and transpose one column at a time and to individually trying to parse each row but being a novice it is getting too complex.

Note: for example shown here, those values are assumed different

Input Dataframe -

[dataframe-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNkX0.png)

Desired Dataframe -

[dataframe-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTXpk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to:

1. Unpivot the columns using [pandas.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) method
2. apply the `pandas.DataFrame.dropna()` method
3. apply [pandas.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Please check if it works.

Comment: Thanks Nemanja! melt() and json_normalize() did the trick. Really appreciate your help!! Being new here I am not sure how can I mark your answer as solution.

Comment: @Tracy Glad I helped. :-) Here are the instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :-)